# Dropbox CoreApi Renam & Move & Updated ( files & folders ) detection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, algorithm

i want to sync my app's file with dropbox ( 2 way sync ), so i have 2 kind of data and i can't use SyncApi of DropBox. so I'm using coreapi;
when i rename a file in cloud, delta says a file with : oldname has been deleted and new file with newname has been added. so after testing many algorithms , i found a way for detect file renaming , but when a folder rename , it has same behavior as rename a file but this time for all files in folder.
I'm looking for a way for handle these events.
any idea for solving these challenges

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
/fileops/move
```

This should rename a folder safely.

Comment: i want to detect what user did on cloud , if user on cloud rename it , i rename it on local.

Comment: Good. Use the api call above to do that.